# why aren't my spans showing inside my div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show some spans inline as if they were a document. However when I load my span tags into my div, they don't appear even though according to the console the div does contain the spans themselves. Not sure if I need to be setting extra parameters of the spans themselves maybe??

```js
var documentbody = document.getElementById("docbod");

/* turns every word in the document into an element then appends them to the div that contains the doc body */
function splitdocintowords(div) {
  var divarray = []
  var state = ["hey", "there", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"]
  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    span = document.createElement("span")
    span.value = state[i]
    span.id = "word" + i;
    span.classList.add("initialTextcolor")
    div.append(span)
  }
  return div
}


/* highlights a selected word within the document*/
function highlight(selection) {
  console.log("selection", selection)
  let element = document.getElementById(selection.id);
  element.classList.add("highlighted");

}
documentbody.value = splitdocintowords(documentbody)
documentbody.addEventListener("mouseup", highlight(window.getSelection()));
```

```html
<h2>doc body</h2>
<div id="docbod" class="docbody"> </div>
```

Comment: span does not have value....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You span was getting appended to the div, but they did not have any content inside since the attribute "value" was set instead of innerText or innerHTML

```js
var documentbody = document.getElementById("docbod");

/* turns every word in the document into an element then appends them to the div that contains the doc body */
function splitdocintowords(div) {
  var state = ["hey", "there", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"]
  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    span = document.createElement("span")
    span.innerHTML = state[i]; //use innerText, innerHTML or textContent here
    span.id = "word" + i;
    span.classList.add("initialTextcolor")
    div.appendChild(span)
  }
}


splitdocintowords(documentbody)
```

```html
<h2>doc body</h2>
<div id="docbod" class="docbody"> </div>
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: sorry I have less than 15 reputation so when I upvote I get:Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `span.value` to `span.innerHTML = state[i]`

```js
var documentbody = document.getElementById("docbod");

/* turns every word in the document into an element then appends them to the div that contains the doc body */
function splitdocintowords(div) {
  var divarray = []
  var state = ["hey", "there", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"]
  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    span = document.createElement("span")
    span.innerHTML = state[i]
    span.id = "word" + i;
    span.classList.add("initialTextcolor")
    div.append(span)
  }
  return div
}

/* highlights a selected word within the document*/
function highlight(selection) {
  console.log("selection", selection)
  let element = document.getElementById(selection.id);
  element.classList.add("highlighted");

}
documentbody.value = splitdocintowords(documentbody)
documentbody.addEventListener("mouseup", highlight(window.getSelection()));
```

```css
#docbod {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<h2>doc body</h2>
<div id="docbod" class="docbody"> </div>
```